# When to use PHP $_SESSION and Cache or when not to use both?

Tags: php, session

I am developing a website and after the login authentication, i am using `$_SESSION` super global array to pass my data to other pages and display when required. This is how i am doing this. Its my own little MVC framework.

```
//please ignore the syntax errors
$recieved_data = $this->registry->{auth_login}($username, $password);

//$recieved_data holds records like (fname,lname,email,username,password)
$_SESSION = $recieved_data;

//Or should i choose PHP cache instead at this point?
```

My website will have a huge traffic after some time. In this particular case, should i choose php cache or keep continue using `$_SESSION`?

I know i cannot ignore the use of sessions completely but what are the right options in my case?

Today, i surprised when i set the `$_SESSION` array with different index names in all the projects and used `print_r($_SESSION)` function to check the available sessions in `$_SESSION Array` in any one of the project.

It showed me all active sessions belonging to different project folders. Is it fine if the `$_SESSION` are globally available in all other projects or its my fault somewhere?

I am  using Xampp 1.8.3 with PHP version 5.5.3 and Netbeans 7.4 (candidate release) for writing code. I would be thankful for expert guideline.

Comment: Make a class for your Sessions, that just uses $_SESSION for now. When/if you have problems you can switch that out for something else. Also you can add an array version that doesn't persist between pages to make it easier to test things.

Comment: What is "PHP Cache"? Never heard of it.

Comment: i mean there are some APIs out there to use cache functionality with PHP.

Comment: @RichBradshaw thanks for your reply. I am going to try what you suggested.

Comment: @SidCh: If you don't know what you actually want to use, how can we then suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

Basic rule: Don't abuse the session as a cache!

Here's why: The session data is read every time a request is made. All of it. And it is written back every time a request ends.

So if you write some data into it as a cache, that isn't used in every request, you are constantly reading and writing data that is not needed in this request.

Low amount of data will not affect performance significantly, but serializing, unserializing and disk or network I/O of huge amounts of data will affect it. And you miss the opportunity to use that data shared between multiple sessions.

On the other hand, a cache is no session storage, for obvious reasons: It is shared between all sessions and cannot really contain private data.

Regarding optimization for more traffic: You cannot optimize right now. Whatever usage pattern will evolve, you will only then see where performance is really needed. And you probably will want to scale - with the easiest way being to scale with some sort of cloud service instead of hosting it on your own hardware.